# Wordpress how to Program Reusable Blocks

Tags: wordpress, block

I have created my own Wordpress theme with css html and php. I need to create some reusable blocks with my own custom html code and with my css classes that can be then edited visually by people that can't program. ( I want to avoid using page builders or many plugins as I would like to achieve a complete control of my code).

- I have tried the custom HTML block but then it can't be visually edited by other people that do not know HTML.
- I have tried using the code editor and some backend functions I created myself but the wpautop removal doesn't work with blocks and I have read in general is not a good practise to have a lot of HTML code in the code editor as it can create problems...
- I thought then to code in the backend each block but visually they won't be able to be edited in the Wordpress dashboard.

What would be the best approach to have customisable blocks ( with html and css) but visually editable by people that do not know how to code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.